# Apache intercept some http Requests

Tags: c++, apache, proxy

I would like to set up with Apache a proxy that intercepts some of the outgoing traffic and calls a third application if the filters are met.

For example, if one device with the ip 10.0.0.13 sends:

GET
/images/01.png
HOST: myinterestingdomain.com

Then Apache should do one one of the following:

- Call directly an executable and send the request & ip as parameters
- Echo that request to a port that the application is listening, and
  also include the ip.
- Anything that triggers my app and sends the
  info

I guess there should be a simple solution for this. Basically: "if the request meets my (regex) criteria do this".

Btw. My application is written in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a filter can also solve the problem but is definitely the longest path.

I discovered that apache has a functionality called piped logs. They do something that is also handy: they send all the requests to my application and then I will filter the requests using regex.

See here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped

thx.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly write your own apache httpd filter. Documentation is a bit sparse but [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/developer/index.html) should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache server provide many kind of filtering way. You could you simply [mod_ext_filter](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html)

to call local executable files. But it's very slow. do not recommend for real service system. Also, you could use [mod_so](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_so.html) which you need to do programming using APACHE API.